# Query to group by daily show as date From-To

Tags: sql, group-by

I have data in table as bellow

```
SERVICE_ID  DATE_SEQ    DAY_SEQ
101004           2012-10-18       1
101004           2012-10-19       2
101001           2012-10-20       3
101004           2012-10-21       4
```

I want query generate date show as range with date {From-to} it will group by Service id and date is sequence,if final it show as
**output:**

```
**Service_id**      **From-To**                **Date**
101004      2012-10-18 - 2012-10-19         1-2
101001      2012-10-20 - 2012-10-20         3-3
101004      2012-10-21 - 2012-10-21         4-4
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get a positive response here, please show what you have tried.

Comment: **SQL** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system (and which version) you're using (like MySQL, SQL Server etc.)

Comment: @user1758769 you tried my response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## try this

```
DECLARE @TB AS TABLE(
  SERVICE_ID INTEGER,
  DATE_SEQ SMALLDATETIME,
  DAY_SEQ NVARCHAR(10),
  FARE_SUP_ID INT
)

INSERT INTO @TB VALUES
  (101004,'2012-10-18 00:00:00',1,267),
  (101001,'2012-10-19 00:00:00',2,171),
  (101004,'2012-10-20 00:00:00',3,267),
  (101004,'2012-10-21 00:00:00',4,171),
  (101001,'2012-10-22 00:00:00',5,171),
  (101001,'2012-10-23 00:00:00',6,171),
  (101004,'2012-10-24 00:00:00',7,267)

SELECT * fROM @TB

;WITH TB1 AS (


SELECT 
  T1.SERVICE_ID,
  MIN(T1.DATE_SEQ) AS CHECK_IN, 
  MAX(T2.DATE_SEQ) AS CHECK_OUT,
  MIN (T1.DAY_SEQ) + ' - ' + MAX(T2.DAY_SEQ) AS DAY_SEQ,
  MAX(T1.FARE_SUP_ID) AS FARE_SUP_ID,
  1 AS DIFF
  FROM @TB T1 INNER JOIN @TB T2
    ON T1.SERVICE_ID = T2.SERVICE_ID
  WHERE DATEDIFF(DY, T1.DATE_SEQ ,T2.DATE_SEQ) = 1
  GROUP BY 
    T1.SERVICE_ID

UNION ALL

SELECT  T3.SERVICE_ID,T3.DATE_SEQ AS CHECK_IN ,T4.DATE_SEQ AS CHECK_OUT 
  ,T3.DAY_SEQ,T3.FARE_SUP_ID,DATEDIFF(DY, T3.DATE_SEQ ,T4.DATE_SEQ)  AS DIFF
  FROM @TB T3 INNER JOIN @TB T4
    ON T3.SERVICE_ID = T4.SERVICE_ID
  WHERE DATEDIFF(DY, T3.DATE_SEQ ,T4.DATE_SEQ) = 0
    AND 
    T3.DATE_SEQ NOT IN (
      SELECT T1.DATE_SEQ
        FROM @TB T1 INNER JOIN @TB T2
          ON T1.SERVICE_ID = T2.SERVICE_ID
        WHERE DATEDIFF(DY, T1.DATE_SEQ ,T2.DATE_SEQ) = 1
    )
    AND 
      T4.DATE_SEQ NOT IN (
        SELECT T2.DATE_SEQ
          FROM @TB T1 INNER JOIN @TB T2
            ON T1.SERVICE_ID = T2.SERVICE_ID
          WHERE DATEDIFF(DY, T1.DATE_SEQ ,T2.DATE_SEQ) = 1
      )
  )
SELECT 
  *
  FROM TB1
  ORDER BY DAY_SEQ
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, the idea is to run inner queries on the main query based on the ID of the main query:

```
select 
SERVICE_ID, 
(select cast(min(DATE_SEQ) AS VARCHAR(20)) from my_table where SERVICE_ID = mt.SERVICE_ID) + ' - ' +(select cast(min(DATE_SEQ) AS VARCHAR(20)) from my_table where SERVICE_ID = mt.SERVICE_ID) as FROM_TO,
(select cast(min(DAY_SEQ) AS VARCHAR(20)) from my_table where SERVICE_ID = mt.SERVICE_ID) + ' - ' +(select cast(min(DAY_SEQ) AS VARCHAR(20)) from my_table where SERVICE_ID = mt.SERVICE_ID) as DATE
from my_table mt
```

Answer (score 0):

I might not have understood the question.

(the CONCAT() function is DBMS dependent, and you might need to cast the dates into text)

This seems a straight forward 'group by' query:

```
SELECT Service_id, 
CONCAT(MIN_DATE," - ", MAX_DATE) AS FromTo,
CONCAT(MIN_SEQ," - ", MAX_SEQ) AS Date
FROM
(
  SELECT Service_id, 
  MIN(DATE_SEQ) AS MIN_DATE, 
  MAX(DATE_SEQ) AS MAX_DATE, 
  MIN(DAY_SEQ) AS MIN_SEQ, 
  MAX(DAY_SEQ) AS MAX_SEQ
  FORM YOUR_TABLE
  GROUP BY Service_id ) AS A
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It is returning different result set. Please verify.

Answer (score 0):

I artificially in the second table is reduced to a sequence of one, for that would join the tables.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (t1.service_id = t2.service_id) THEN t1.service_id ELSE t2.service_id END AS service_id,
       CASE WHEN (t1.service_id = t2.service_id) THEN CAST(t1.date_seq AS nvarchar(10)) + ' - ' + CAST(t2.date_seq AS nvarchar(10)) 
                                                 ELSE CAST(t2.date_seq AS nvarchar(10)) + ' - ' + CAST(t2.date_seq AS nvarchar(10)) END AS date_seq,
       CASE WHEN (t1.service_id = t2.service_id) THEN CAST(t1.day_seq AS nvarchar(10)) + ' - ' + CAST(t2.day_seq AS nvarchar(10)) 
                                                 ELSE CAST(t2.day_seq AS nvarchar(10)) + ' - ' + CAST(t2.day_seq AS nvarchar(10)) END AS day_seq                                                              
FROM dbo.test28 t1 INNER JOIN dbo.test28 t2 ON t1.day_seq = t2.day_seq - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will work for sure (even if days are missing in between) -

```
--STEP 1. CREATE DUMMY TABLE WITH DUPLICATE_SEQ COLUMN. YOU MAY ADD ONE MORE COLUMN IN
--SAME TABLE
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (SERVICE_ID  INT, DATE_SEQ  DATETIME,  DAY_SEQ INT,  DUPLICATE_SEQ INT DEFAULT(0))

INSERT INTO @TABLE(SERVICE_ID, DATE_SEQ, DAY_SEQ)  VALUES
(101004,           '2012-10-18',       1),
(101004,           '2012-10-19',      2),
(101001,           '2012-10-20',       3),
(101004,           '2012-10-21',       4)

--STEP 2. LOGIC TO UPDATE TABLE WITH DUPLICATE_SEQ VALUE FOR SEQUENTIAL DUPLICATES ONLY
DECLARE @PREVIOUS_SERVICE_ID INT
DECLARE @DUPLICTE_COUNTER INT = 1

SET @PREVIOUS_SERVICE_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 SERVICE_ID FROM @TABLE)

UPDATE @TABLE
SET 
DUPLICATE_SEQ = @DUPLICTE_COUNTER
,@DUPLICTE_COUNTER = CASE WHEN @PREVIOUS_SERVICE_ID = SERVICE_ID THEN @DUPLICTE_COUNTER ELSE @DUPLICTE_COUNTER + 1  END
,@PREVIOUS_SERVICE_ID = CASE WHEN @PREVIOUS_SERVICE_ID = SERVICE_ID THEN @PREVIOUS_SERVICE_ID ELSE SERVICE_ID  END

--STEP 3. LOGIC TO UPDATE TABLE WITH DUPLICATE_SEQ VALUE FOR SEQUENTIAL DUPLICATES ONLY    
SELECT SERVICE_ID AS 'Service_id'
    , CONVERT(CHAR(10), MIN(DATE_SEQ), 126) + ' - ' + CONVERT(CHAR(10), MAX(DATE_SEQ), 126) AS 'From-To'
    , CAST(MIN(DAY_SEQ) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' - ' + CAST(MAX(DAY_SEQ) AS VARCHAR(10)) AS 'Date'
FROM @TABLE
GROUP BY DUPLICATE_SEQ, SERVICE_ID
ORDER BY 3 ASC
```

**OUTPUT**  **-**

```
Service_id  From-To                      Date
101004      2012-10-18 - 2012-10-19      1 - 2
101001      2012-10-20 - 2012-10-20      3 - 3
101004      2012-10-21 - 2012-10-21      4 - 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer , try from your script is very grate but i have issue that if i add data from below as 

(101004,           '2012-10-18',       1),
(101004,           '2012-10-19',      2),
(101001,           '2012-10-20',       3),
(101001,           '2012-10-21',       4),
(101002,           '2012-10-22',       5),
(101004,           '2012-10-23',       6),
(101004,           '2012-10-24',       7)

that result still is show not correct..

thank you

Comment: I have modified UPDATE @TABLE statement above. Please verify.